# Why HTML page inserted in popup with document.write needs a refresh to load in IE 7/8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, window.open, document.write

I have a weird scenario... after struggling with it for over 3 hours I decided to ask a question.

I'm opening a `popup` window with this code:

```
var mapWin = window.open('', '', params);

mapWin.document.open();
mapWin.document.write(map);
mapWin.document.close();
```

where `map` makes use of Esri [bootstrap-map-js](https://github.com/Esri/bootstrap-map-js/) and contains the full `HTML` code of a page I get through an `AJAX` call. This page's code includes `<link>` and `<script>` tags.

Everything works great on Firefox and Google Chrome as always. :) The problem is with ***finicky*** `IE 7/8`. When testing with `IE 11 Developer Tools` and the document mode set to `IE 7` or `IE 8`, `document.write` puts the content in the new window however it seems it's not executing/running some of the `<script>` included in `map` - as a result map is not rendered on the screen.

The weird thing is that if I right-click the popup window and select Refresh, then the page renders as expected and I can see the map.

Note: all scripts are located at `localhost`, that is, my own machine.

Any ideas about what can be causing such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely ditched opening a ***popup***. It's such a pain to work with them and not so user friendly given that there are popup blockers spread all over...

What I did was this:

Created a `<form>` element and assigned its action pointing to a controller action in my ASP.NET MVC app.

```
<form id="mapform" action="myproject/map/ArcGisMap" target="_blank" method="post"></form>
```

Take note about the `target="_blank"`.

I also have a `<button>`:

```
<button type="button" id="arcGISMap">ArcGIS Map</button>
```

Then with some `jQuery` code we can simulate a form submit when clicking that button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#arcGISMap").click(function()
{
    $('#mapform').submit();
});

</script>
```

Because the form has a `target="_blank"` when it's submitted it'll open a new browser tab. Just what I wanted. That browser *tab* (***not*** a new popup window) now has the `View` returned by the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ArcGISMap()
{
    return View();
}
```

On my `Razor` view I added this:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Setting the `Layout` to `null` allows me to render only the map on the screen.